# Is it possible to change files and commit on git pre-receive/pre-push hook?

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

I'm Looking at implementing a *pre-recieve/pre-push* hook(Not aware which one should be used)

**Use case**:

I have a repository of JSONs, any one can change the files in repo(i.e commit). But on push, I would like to calculate the diffs (i.e files added/deleted/modified) against the upstream and store it as another JSON file in the repository and continue the push along with the new JSON that was added.

Is this possible?

Comment: It *might* be possible (although I haven't tried this). However, I wouldn't advise it. A commit is a change to the code base and there should be a person responsible. Who will this new commit be by? If it breaks the build, whose responsibility is it to fix the problem? Can you detail the problem you're  trying to solve? Why are you changing this file and committing automatically? Perhaps there's a better solution.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I have elaborated the question detail.

Comment: @Karthik do you means new changes are pushed to remote by other developers and you want to calculate the diffs with your local branch? But if there has new changes on remote, you will stop you pushing and hint with git pull first.

Comment: @Karthik and you can't use pre-receive hook directly since remote repo don't has working directory.

Answer (score 0):

pre-recieve is a server side hook. Based on your requirement, you'd better use pre-commit or pre-push hook. And the hooks can change a certain file.

Such as for pre-commit hooke, you can use below script to add `string` to filename and commit the changes when you are commit changes:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "string" >> filename
git add filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This information which you need is trivially computable. A git diff between versions can give you the information you need. Keeping it in a file runs the risk of things going of of sync. I'd much prefer that this were generated on the fly as needed directly from the repository rather than read out of a cache. So, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. However, if I did need it, I'd go about this in one of the following ways.

1. A post-commit hook that will make this change on the client side before pushing it. This has the downside that people will see commits in their code that they didn't make.
2. Providing a script that will do this and disallowing pushes (using a serve side hook) until the user runs the script and generates this information in the repository. This makes it a little manual but the user knows what he or she has done and is in control.
3. Having a script run on the server after the commit (perhaps in batches) which will generate this information and store it preferably in a separate repository.